# How can I force asyncio task to run?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm noticing that when I spawn an asyncio task using `create_task`, it's first completing the rest of the logic rather than starting that task. I'm forced to add an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to get the task started, which seems a bit hacky and unclean to me.

Here is some example code:

```
async def make_rpc_calls(...some args...)
  val_1, val_2 = await asyncio.gather(rpc_call_1(...), rpc_call_2(...))
  return process(val_1, val_2)

def some_very_cpu_intensive_function(...some args...):
  // Does a lot of computation, can take 20 seconds to run
  
task_1 = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(make_rpc_calls(...))
intensive_result = some_very_cpu_intensive_function(...)
await task_1
process(intensive_result, task_1.result())
```

Anytime I run the above, it runs the `some_very_cpu_intensive_function` function before the kicking off the expensive RPCs. The only way I've gotten this to work is to do:

```
async def make_rpc_calls(...some args...)
  val_1, val_2 = await asyncio.gather(rpc_call_1(...), rpc_call_2(...))
  return process(val_1, val_2)

def some_very_cpu_intensive_function(...some args...):
  // Does a lot of computation, can take 20 seconds to run

task_1 = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(make_rpc_calls(...))

await asyncio.sleep(0)

intensive_result = some_very_cpu_intensive_function(...)
await task_1
process(intensive_result, task_1.result())
```

This feels like a hack to me - I'm forcing the event loop to context switch, and doesn't feel like I'm using the asyncio framework correctly. Is there another way I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sleep() always suspends the current task, allowing other tasks to run.
>
> Setting the delay to 0 provides an optimized path to allow other tasks to run. This can be used by long-running functions to avoid blocking the event loop for the full duration of the function call.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: I guess what I was looking for is in the sleep section and not task section. I must have read the docs and kept missing it. Thanks! Follow up question - why use this over concurrent.futures? Futures seems way more intuitive, readable and writeable to me, and doesn’t require this propagation of coroutine-ness everywhere in the system.

Comment: Well, normally there is no need to create Future objects at the application level code since like Tasks are futures-like objects. At least I have never needed to use them